# SVN update-commit Hook help needed

Tags: linux, svn

We have a Linux based web server (Media Temple) where we host several domains via their DV hosting solution. I have successfully created the SVN repository for one of our projects but now I would like it to sync the live web folder on committ. Both the repo and the site files are on the same server... Paths are as follows:

The SVN Repo is here: /home/svn/repositories/<site name>

The Live Site files are here: /var/www/vhosts/<domain>/httpdocs/<subdomain>

I can connect to the repo without problem. The live site works as well. Now I just need to get them to sync.

I have created the following update file as per guide and correctly updated the POST-COMMIT.tmpl but still no dice.
http://www.frenssen.be/content/using-subversion-automatically-update-live-website

Here is the code in my update program:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(void)
{
    execl("/usr/bin/svn", "svn", "update",
        "/var/www/vhosts/<domain>/httpdocs/<subdomain>",
        (const char *) NULL);
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And I called the program in the POST-COMMIT.tmpl file with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/svn/repositories/autoupdate/autoupdate
```

Any ideas what I am missing? There has to be an easier way to get the files to sync?

Answer (score 2):

You need to rename `post-commit.tmpl` to `post-commit`—that is, remove the `.tmpl` suffix. See [“Implementing Repository Hooks” from *Version Control with Subversion.*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) (The .tmpl files are named as such to show they're examples, templates upon which to build your own scripts.)

Also, the guide you referenced suggests changing ownership of the hook to apache. They actually mean whichever user owner your repository (which is apparently apache for the guide writer).

Comment: I just renamed the file and dropped the .tmpl
- restarted the Daemon
- made a change to a file in the repo and committed it, nothing happened.
- also went to the /home/avn/autoupdate folder and ran the script by ./autoupdate. The script executed but again nothing changed with the live server files...

Comment: To try and troubleshoot a possible permission issue I made the entire path to the live server chmod 777. This time when I went to the script and executed it manually I get the following:

Skipped '/var/www/vhosts/<WEB SITE NAME>/httpdocs/<SUB DOMAIN>'

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx: Is that actually a checkout? What happens if you `cd` into that directory, and run `svn up` by hand?

Comment: Got the Following:

+ svn up
U    index.php
U    views/newReminder.php
U    views/edit_job.php
Updated to revision 9.

Answer (score 0):

No actually an answer (yet) but you could adapt and execute these commands on your server to gather some information about your setup:

```
REPO=/home/svn/repositories/XYZ
WORK=/var/www/vhosts/FOO/httpdocs/BAR

set -x

ls -ld $REPO $REPO/hooks $REPO/hooks/post-commit* $REPO/db/revs
head -2 $REPO/hooks/post-commit | hexdump -C
svnlook youngest $REPO

ls -ld $WORK $WORK/.svn $WORK/.svn/entries
svn info $WORK
```

Please attach the output to your question.

**Edit** The output has been pasted unformatted into a series of comments. Here is the relavant part:

```
svn info $WORK 
+ svn info /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/ 
svn: '/var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30' is not a working copy 

ls -ld $WORK $WORK/.svn $WORK/.svn/entries 
+ ls --color=tty -ld /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/ /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn/entries

ls: /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn: No such file or directory 
ls: /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn/entries: No such file or directory 
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Oct 19 13:15 /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/
```

That means, that $WORK is not a SVN-working copy. The link in your question explains the required steps in the section "Step 1: check out the repository to the web root"

Comment: Here is what I have:

[root@myspiderdesign autoupdate]# REPO=/home/svn/repositories/baportal/
[root@myspiderdesign autoupdate]# WORK=/var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/
[root@myspiderdesign autoupdate]# set -x
++ echo -ne '\033]0;root@myspiderdesign:/home/svn/autoupdate'

Comment: [root@myspiderdesign autoupdate]# ls -ld $REPO $REPO/hooks $REPO/hooks/post-commit* $REPO/db/revs
+ ls --color=tty -ld /home/svn/repositories/baportal/ /home/svn/repositories/baportal//hooks /home/svn/repositories/baportal//hooks/post-commit /home/svn/repositories/baportal//db/revs
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   root   4096 Oct 19 13:19 /home/svn/repositories/baportal/
drwxr-sr-x 3 root   root   4096 Oct 19 13:18 /home/svn/repositories/baportal//db/revs
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Oct 19 14:41 /home/svn/repositories/baportal//hooks-rwxr--r-- 1 apache apache 2098

Comment: [root@myspiderdesign autoupdate]# svn info $WORK
+ svn info /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/
svn: '/var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30' is not a working copy
++ echo -ne '\033]0;root@myspiderdesign:/home/svn/autoupdate'

Comment: [root@myspiderdesign autoupdate]# ls -ld $WORK $WORK/.svn $WORK/.svn/entries
+ ls --color=tty -ld /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/ /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn/entries

Comment: ls: /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn: No such file or directory
ls: /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30//.svn/entries: No such file or directory
drwxrwxrwx 8 root root 4096 Oct 19 13:15 /var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/
++ echo -ne '\033]0;root@myspiderdesign:/home/svn/autoupdate'

Comment: @xXPhenom22Xx It seems, your `$WORK` does not point to a real SVN working copy, because there is no `.svn` directory below it. (see "is not a working copy" and "no such file or..." messages)  Did you do a `svn co` there?

Comment: No I dont think so... Here is what I did. We have had a working copy of a site and decided we need a repo we all can work off of.

I created an SVN repo successfully at /home/svn/repositories/baportal/

imported files into the repo from /var/www/vhosts/.... (The LIVE SITE)

Now when we update the repo or make changes to it I was hoping these was a way to update the live site files at /var/www.vhosts....

Comment: I tried backing up the live site, removing the folder, creating a repo and adding the files. But when I did this and tried to view it I got nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and sorry for the n00b questions. Havent done any command line SVN work before....

In any event I deleted the folder where the live site was and then did the Import which is the step I missed! The files were checked out with no issues. 

I remapped my repo to my IDE and made some changes and committed them, again no issues. I didnt see any changes impact the live site so I ran the script manually and got this message this time:

Comment: svn: Can't open file '/var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/.svn/lock': Permission denied

Comment: This is a permission problem. Is the `autoupdate` binary still `suid` root? Does `ls -l autoupdate` say something like `-rwsr-sr-x root root...`? If not, then do the `chmod  +s` command from the linked blog.

Answer (score 0):

1. WC inside web-tree is **always bad idea**
2. When you imported site to repo, it will not convert site automagically to WC
3. If you *still want* ignore my p.1, you must 1 time perform svn co (to emptied previously??? TBT) site location in order to get WC in it
4. More correct way for post-commit hook (from my POV) is remove all old data from site and svn export HEAD to site-path

Comment: I removed the site folder then did a SVN Checkout which imported all of the files and folder exactly the way I want it. The live site still loads after the import and all looks well on the front.

When making a change to a file in the repo and committing I didnt see any immediate change so I went to the autoupdate script and ran it manually. Got the following:

 
svn: Can't open file '/var/www/vhosts/unionjobtracker.com/httpdocs/pdc30/.svn/lock': Permission denied

Comment: file ownership or permission, obviously. update require write rights for a set of different files (inside .svn dir also), but you aren't www-user, I think

Comment: I had to add on "--username", "username","--password","password" and now the script is updating without issue. Thanks for the help.